# Unable to locate element Selenium:

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
    tos = driver.find_element_by_id("TOS_CHECKBOX").click()
    check_out = driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn btn--small-wide")
    check_out.click()
```

Link to website: https://www.squidindustries.co/cart

I'm able to check the terms of service box but then when I try to click the checkout button I am  given an error of "no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".btn btn--small-wide"}" I've tried time.sleep and driver.implicitly_wait but neither seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below css  :

```
input[value='Check out']
```

in code :

```
check_out = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[value='Check out']")
check_out.click()
```

or

With Explicit waits  :

```
checkout = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[value='Check out']")))
checkout.click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the `explicitWait`

```
checkbox=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@id='TOS_CHECKBOX' and @type='checkbox']")))
checkbox.click()

checkout = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@type='button' and @class='btn btn--small-wide']")))
checkout.click()
```

**import**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
```